# short vertical line in footer fancyhdr

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, vertical, footer

I'm having trouble to get the vertical line in the footer shorter. I don't want the line to be pulled through to the bottom of the page. Instead I want it either only the height of the page number or a bit longer like double, the line going also down not up. So either I can define the length or smash, idk please help.

With the geometry package I can get the page number down, but that's not what I want.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\vfootline\hskip\linepagesep\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\newskip\linepagesep \linepagesep 5pt\relax
\def\vfootline{%
   \begingroup\color{blue}\rule[-990pt]{1pt}{1000pt}\endgroup}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
   \lipsum
   \lipsum
   \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the options for `\rule`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\vfootline\hspace{\linepagesep}\thepage}

\newlength\linepagesep
\setlength{\linepagesep}{5pt}
\newcommand*\vfootline{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[-2pt]{1pt}{2\ht\strutbox}}}

\begin{document}
   \lipsum
   \lipsum
   \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax of `\rule` is

```
\rule[<vertical shift>]{<width of the rule>}{<height of the rule>}
```

If the rule should go down you could use eg.

```
\rule[-\ht\strutbox]{1pt}{2\ht\strutbox}
```

[image]

---

Remark: You are using a KOMA-Script class. So it is recommended to use package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside,footheight=23pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rofoot*{\vfootline\hspace{\linepagesep}\pagemark}
\lefoot*{\pagemark\hspace{5pt}\vfootline}% for twosided document

\newlength\linepagesep
\setlength{\linepagesep}{5pt}
\newcommand*\vfootline{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[-2pt]{1pt}{2\ht\strutbox}}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Other example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,footlines=2]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ultramarineblue}{rgb}{0.25, 0.4, 0.96}

\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chaptername\ \thechapter\autodot\ \ }

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark}
\rofoot*{\vfootline\hspace{\linepagesep}\pagemark}
\lefoot*{\pagemark\hspace{5pt}\vfootline}% for twosided document

\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{ultramarineblue}}

\newlength\linepagesep
\setlength{\linepagesep}{5pt}
\newcommand*\vfootline{{\usekomafont{headsepline}\rule[-2pt]{1pt}{2\ht\strutbox}}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{CTitle}
   \lipsum
    \section{STitle}
   \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the star in `\rofoot*` and `\lefoot*` ensures that page style `plain` will use the same contents as page style `scrheadings`. By default chapter pages get page style `plain`.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it so bad to use fancyhdr? I have some other things I use that I need fancyhdr for. And it works fine. Btw I'm a newbie to Latex.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\definecolor{ultramarineblue}{rgb}{0.25, 0.4, 0.96}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Turn on the style
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{ultramarineblue}%
    \hrule width\headwidth height\headrulewidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\fancyhead[R]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\vfootline\hspace{\linepagesep}\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[R]{\vfootline\hspace{\linepagesep}\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\newlength\linepagesep
\setlength{\linepagesep}{5pt}
\newcommand*\vfootline{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[-2pt]{1pt}{2\ht\strutbox}}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{CTitle}
   \lipsum
    \section{STitle}
   \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a new answer to your question but a comment to my answer. It it would be really, really bad to use `fancyhdr` my first suggestion would not use this package. But `fancyhdr` breaks some KOMA-Script features. Eg. options `headsepline`, `footsepline` etc. does not have an affect and you can not use `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont` to change the font of page header and footer etc. So it is recommended to use the KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-scrpage` while it is still possible to use `fancyhdr`.