# Partial rule over footer page numbers

Tags: fancyhdr, rules, scrreprt

I am using KOMA's scrreprt together with fancyhdr and want my page numbers on the outside of each page. So I use:

```
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

which works as expected. Now, how do I add a short horizontal line (rule) above the page number? The rule should cover about one third of the page width.

Comment: Of the text width or of the paper width?

Comment: @Bernard: Of the paper width. Also, the line should start at the paper edge.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8473/197451

Comment: @user1583209  does the answer meet your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. Then you can enable the `footsepline` and adjust its layer:

```latex
\documentclass[
  twoside
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\KOMAoptions{
  footsepline=1pt:.3333\paperwidth,% syntax: footsepline=<thickness>:<length>
  plainfootsepline,
  olines
}
\ModifyLayer[
  hoffset=0pt,
  width=\paperwidth,
  addvoffset=-5pt% move the line up
]{scrheadings.foot.above.line}
\RedeclareLayer[
  clone=scrheadings.foot.above.line
]{plain.scrheadings.foot.above.line}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{footsepline}{\color{red!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

please see if this suits your requirement -- code edited from -- [short vertical line in footer fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413759/short-vertical-line-in-footer-fancyhdr)

You can experiment with `\hspace{-4cm}` for moving the entire line left or right toward the page margins

You can experiment with `\rule[10pt]{7cm}{6pt}` to change the length height and thickness of the line alone

Disadvantages of using `fancyhdr` with KOMA are given at the website shortcut provided at top

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside,footheight=23pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\rofoot*{\vfootline\hspace{-4cm}\pagemark}
\lefoot*{\pagemark\hspace{-4cm}\vfootline}% for twosided document

\newlength\linepagesep
\setlength{\linepagesep}{5pt}
\newcommand*\vfootline{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[10pt]{7cm}{6pt}}}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
Other example
```